# ExpanderView port for Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: winrt-xaml

I've started the process of porting over the toolkit version myself today and want to see if anybody has done this previously. I haven't been able to find resource off of the microsoft forums. I noticed one person has done this here or at least is part way into porting.

I'll update with specific technical difficulties as I go along.

Seems like something a lot of people would need to use in their universal phone apps since its a part of the design practices for wp development.

Comment: I'd suggest creating one in WinRT XAML Toolkit since it already has a`HeaderedItemsControl` ported over. I'd consider a pull request. It doesn't have a working NuGet package for the phone yet though.

Comment: I've never actually used the `ExpanderView`, but it seems to me like you might be better off writing some custom code if you want to retain virtualization support and be able to work in a `GridView` as in the WinRT XAML Toolkit sample app's home page. It seems like it might be a simple way to get an expanding view up and running quickly, but it won't virtualize well and the items won't wrap as they would need to in a `GridView`.